# Stream shoutcast on HTTPS site from a different HTTP streaming server

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, jplayer, icecast, shoutcast

Up until several weeks ago I was able to stream icecast and shoutcast on my HTTPS site. This would create a "mixed content" warning but was never explicitly blocked.

Now I find that chrome is forcing the `http://streaminglink` urls to load `https://streaminglink` and I can't access the http audio anymore.

Here is a code example in jPlayer

```
$("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer("setMedia", {      
                mp3:"http://149.202.79.68:8213/stream.mp3" 
});
```

I expect chrome to load the http url but **instead it is looking for the https** and I get the following error in the console:

> GET https://149.202.79.68:8213/stream.mp3 net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

**NOTE** 
The https ^ - that's not coming from my code or configuration... =/

Comment: Given that you explicitly tagged the question Icecast, that would be my suggestion. Switch to Icecast as it has HTTPS support. (In case of Debian/Ubuntu, make sure to get the Xiph.org package, as distro is built without openssl)

Comment: Chrome doesn't do that automatically.  Undoubtedly, there's a bug in some code you're not showing here.

Comment: I can confirm this is happening on Chrome and it's not Server-Side.  I can listen to a stream on iPhone/Safari but not on Chrome (PC or Android)

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like this is default behavior for Chrome since 79.
https://www.engadget.com/2019/10/04/chrome-security-block-http-content/

Broke my site. Thanks Google.

Answer (score -1):

you can now allow insecure content in the specific site settings

chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=https%3A%2F%2F<SITE_DOMAIN>